# "No operator matches the given name and argument types" when I subtract two columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to subtract two columns in Postgres and save the result in a third column but I can't really get it working. I use MacOS Postgres13.0.

**My database looks like follows**:

```
 id  |    date    | new_infections | new_deaths | new_recovered | active_cases 
-----+------------+----------------+------------+---------------+--------------
  16 | 2020/03/21 | 111            | 0          | 12            | 
  17 | 2020/03/23 | 213            | 3          | 0             | 
  18 | 2020/03/24 | 25             | 1          | 0             |
```

**I tried basic stuff first, such as**:

```
SELECT *, new_infections - new_deaths AS active_cases FROM covid_stats_poland;
```

**I also tried**:

```
UPDATE covid_stats_poland
SET active_cases = new_infections - new_deaths - new_recovered;
```

But I am getting "HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." all the time. Can anyone advise please?

I am trying to do the following calculation:

```
new_infections - new_deaths - new_recovered
```

and save it as active_cases by a query for all rows.

Comment: Edit your question and explain what calculation you are trying to make.

Comment: It is because you are using text type instead of integer for your columns.

Comment: Why are you saving something that can be easily calculated in a query when needed? It's a waste of storage space in the DB, and can lead to discrepancies in the data. What happens when you do the original insert, store the `active_cases`, and then someone edits `new_infections` or one of the other columns? Your `active_cases` is now wrong.

Comment: @Abelisto: Nice catch! I missed the column alignment to the left.

Comment: Wow okay @Abelisto thanks, that was dumb...

Answer (score 1):

It was actually because my columns were `varchar` instead of `integer`.